# iscsi multipath on CentOS 7, is it possible with existing partition

Tags: linux, storage, iscsi, netapp

I have an ISCSI server (NetApp) with multipath support, initially i login (iscsi login from client) with one controller and created an iscsi partition (sdb) in CentOS 7.

Also i copied some data's into it. 
Now i need to configure multipathing but i don't want to loose my data.

Is it safe/possible to login to the next controller (sdc) and create multipath with out loosing existing data?

Answer (score 4):

Configuring and adding multipath to existing iSCSI disk should not somehow affect data on it. You need to disconnect iSCSI target -> configure multipath on CenOS site -> and then reconnect iSCSI disk using multiple paths.

Comment: May be it will work, i didn't took the risk . I created another iscsi  LUN and copied all data and configured multipath .